# Android Device not showing up in VS15

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, adb

I just got Xamarin project from my client and when i open it in VS15 its not showing up ADB devices attached.When i open CMD and get number of attached devices i got all devices up and running fine but in this specific project its not showing any attached devices and only showing "Start Button". To make sure i followed steps like installing USB driver and restarting VS + enabling USB debugging many times but non of them work for me.I have also tried many other methods found on Stackoverflow

I also want to add that the minimum SDK is set to 10 and Target SDK is set to 13 in ProjectNameAndroidMenifest.xml

[image: It is only showing start button and few devices in a list of Unsupported Devices]

Comment: already checked many times

Comment: i have tried more then 100 times but still can try one more time

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is you don't have your Android project set as the startup project in VS. All you need to do is right click you Android Project and select `Set as Startup Project` and your devices/emulators should appear correctly.

Comment: Are you sure because it would usually only show the Start button if the wrong project was set as startup. I would also check the configuration manager to makes sure it's set to deploy.

Comment: 110% sure. i have shown my project to person having 5 year experience he was also unable to find error. he said project has issue but its was running on previous dev laptop

Comment: Weird and I wonder if it might do this because of the min and target sdk versions are so old. I would maybe try changing those and rebuilding to see if it helps.

Comment: i have doubled check this but still its not showing any devices only start button.

Comment: At this point, all I can suggest is maybe try creating a new Android project and copy all their files over or try it in VS 2017/see if the same thing happens on another computer entirely.

Comment: so i solved this error. you can not believe what i have done and this will make no logic. i make new androidmanifest,.xml and copy and paste content of old.and ta dahhhh app is showing devices

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

Make sure Android SDK is installed
Locate adb.exe. For me it was in C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

open CMD and run "adb devices".
restart Visual Studio